# WebGL билд Unity зависает в случайный момент

Tags: unity3d, webgl, unity3d-ui

Игра зависает и перестает отвечать через некоторое время (10-20 секунд) после запуска.
Чаще всего это происходит при выполнении активных действий, например взаимодействия с UI кнопками или включения/выключения объектов. В какой-то момент игра просто перестает реагировать на действия игрока, перестает рендерить новые кадры. При всем этом в Editor`е всё нормально.

Игра состоит из UI панелей, чаще всего игра зависает на второй из них, либо после её появления либо после взаимодействия с кнопками (наведения курсора, нажатия)

Версия Unity: 2022.3.4f1

**На что мне следует обратить внимание, если в редакторе Unity все работает без нареканий?**

[image: Панель 1]
[image: Панель 2]

Comment: Столкнулся с той же проблемой при переходе на более новую версию Unity. Вы не нашли решение?

Comment: здравствуйте, ошибка была в моём коде: я много раз вызывал очень тяжёлую функцию, в эдиторе было нормально, а браузер видимо задыхался. можете проверить свой код на такое, хотя в вашем случае, вероятно, проблема в другом